# Как сделать background-image ?

Tags: css

Как сделать background-image, что-бы изображение расплылось на 100%х100%, только не умножалось?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На это способно свойство [background-size](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-size), но его поддерживают только современный браузере, в старых нужно такой фон делать тегом img

```
img{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; // для ие
}
```

такая картинка будет расстягиваться сохраняя пропорции

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
background: url(yourimg.jpg);
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   .block-name {
      background-image: url("bg.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```